# Singleton template with variadic constructor class

Tags: c++, singleton

I'm trying to implement singleton template which could instantiate (from template argument) object of the class by ctor with some set of the parameters.
The code below looks ordinary and working.

```
template <typename T>
class Singleton
{
public:
    template<typename... Ts>
    static T &instance(Ts &&...args)
    {
        static T instance{std::forward<Ts>(args)...};
        return instance;
    }

protected:
    Singleton() = default;
    ~Singleton() = default;

    Singleton(const Singleton &) = delete;
    Singleton &operator=(const Singleton &) = delete;
};
```

there is an interesting question:

if we are trying to get the instance using different ctors, intuitively expected that is a single instance:

```
// create with T with some specific parameters
Singleton<MyClass>::instance(1, nullptr, "test").dosomething();
// ....
// use such version for simpler notation 
// or where the paramters are not available 
Singleton<MyClass>::instance().dosomething();
```

In C++ template terms, obviously the instances are a different due of different instantiations of template instance() function.

if we write "old style" singleton (Meyer's version) based on member pointer to the instance, it solves the problem as the instance will be outside of template class method.

So the question is - is there some technique to keep "reference-style" singleton and keep this outside of "instance()" function to prevent different instances ? or anything else?

Comment: what if `T` does have different constructors? How do you determine which one is "ok" and which one not? In your example which line should fail and which one should suceed?

Comment: anyhow it is an odd design that everytime you want to access the instance you need to pass the parameters for the constructor, but they are not used (only on the first call)

Comment: yes, T has a few ctors, and what you mean "ok" or "not"? and both lines (of singleton using) should be succeeded , and use the same instance of T

Comment: so the first line creates the instance via the default constructor and in the next line all arguments are ignored?

Comment: changed the post (swap usage lines) and added the comments. hope this clarifies your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the instance in a static member. The advantage of the meyers singleton is that initialization of the instance is thread safe just by how a local static varible works. Though the same can be achieved differently. As also the `static` requires the implementation to use some sort of synchronization mechanism, I do not expect too much difference in terms of performance when an explicit synchronization mechanism is used. I use `std::once` here.

```
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> class Singleton {
public:
    template<typename... Ts> static T& instance(Ts &&...args) {
        std::call_once(once,[&](){
            _instance = std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
        });
        return *_instance;
    }
protected:
    static std::unique_ptr<T> _instance;
    static std::once_flag once;
    Singleton() = default;
    ~Singleton() = default;
    Singleton(const Singleton &) = delete;
    Singleton &operator=(const Singleton &) = delete;
};

template <typename T> std::unique_ptr<T> Singleton<T>::_instance;
template <typename T> std::once_flag Singleton<T>::once;

struct T {
    int value;
    T(int x) : value(x) { std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl; }   
    T() = default;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << Singleton<T>::instance(42).value;
    std::cout << Singleton<T>::instance().value;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rr14Pb76P) (note the `-pthread`, without it will segfault).

`std::call_once` ensures that only one thread enters the function and only reach the `return` when `_instance` is initialized. Effectively it is the same as the `static` local.

The caveat is that `Singleton<T>::instance()` only compiles when `T` has a default constructor, otherwise it not (https://godbolt.org/z/TMdGe16re). I felt that this is beyond the question being asked here and did not include a solution. You can optionally add a `instance()` overload that does not call the constuctor but throws an exception when `_instance` is not yet initialized for the case when `T` cannot be default constructed.

Last and least the usual dislaimer against the singleton pattern: Don't, blablablbla blablabla blablablubb, globals are evil, blablablubb.

Comment: that's a good reply, my current implementation is a similar. just asked to make sure that there is no some technique implement this in value/reference style instead of pointer one

Comment: @amigo421 note that the method still does return a reference. The pointer is only necessary to be in control of when the instance is initialized.

Comment: suppose static members can be made as inline to avoid out of the class definitions?